# TChart отображение подсказки при простом НАВЕДЕНИИ (а не клике) мышки на метку

Tags: delphi, диаграммы

Имеется *TChart* и свой метод/событие, которое выводит подсказку (возле метки) по нажатию мышкой на метку

```
procedure TForm.Series1Click(Sender: TChartSeries; ValueIndex: Integer;
  Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Chart1.ShowHint := true;
  Chart1.Hint := DateToStr(Series1.XValue[ValueIndex]);
end;
```

Событие

> procedure TFDiagram.Series1MouseLeave(Sender: TObject); 
>   begin
>   Chart1.ShowHint := false;
>   end;

не дает подсказке выпадать когда курсор не над точкой на графике.

Мне нужно, чтобы подсказка выводилась не по нажатию кнопки мышки на метке, а просто при подводе курсора мышки к метке

Я пробовал

```
procedure TForm. Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
  var
  Button: TMouseButton;
begin
  Series1.OnClick(nil, 1, Button, Shift, x, y); - не подходит
end;
```

но он не подходит, т.к. в событие OnClick, нужно передававать номер метки/индекса

Как мне поступить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать MouseMove, но не нужно из него пытаться вызвать обработчик другого события. Нужно самому получить данные/дипазон данных, используя координаты курсора и свойство `Series.Clicked`, которое сообщает, был ли выделен данный график или нет (под выделением понимается как раз наведение мыши на график/точку/бар/круг и т.п.):

```
    procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
      Y: Integer);
    var
      SeriesIndex: Integer;
    begin
      SeriesIndex := Series1.Clicked(X, Y);
      Chart1.ShowHint := SeriesIndex <> -1;
      if Chart1.ShowHint then           
          Chart1.Hint:='Y='+FormatFloat('#.00',Series1.YValue[SeriesIndex]) + ' Legend: '+Series1.ValueMarkText[SeriesIndex];
    end;
```

Данный код покажет подсказку, в которой выдаст значение ординаты точки, к которой подвели мышь, для точечного графика и легенду для точки

Или вот так:

```
procedure TForm1.Chart1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  SeriesIndex: Integer;
begin
  SeriesIndex := Series1.Clicked(X, Y);

  Chart1.ShowHint := SeriesIndex <> -1;
  if Chart1.ShowHint then 
     Chart1.Hint:='Y='+FormatFloat('#.00',Series1.YScreenToValue(y)) + ' Legend: '+Series1.ValueMarkText[SeriesIndex+1];
end;
```

Данный код покажет подсказку для линейного графика: в любом месте, куда мы подведем мышь, будет показана высчитанная ордината для точки и легенда для точки, оканчивающей отрезок.
Если у вас несколько графиков на одном Chart'е, то опрашивать надо все `Series[i].Clicked`.

Comment: Viktor Tomilov, Спасибо...

Comment: То есть можно заставить TChart  показывать значения Y в любой точке графика?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov да, Series1.YScreenToValue(y) (либо Series[i].YScreenToValue(y) в случае многих серий) это вам позволяют

Comment: @Viktor Tomilov, Вы писали что, если есть несколько серий на одном TChart, то можно воспользоваться *if Series1.Clicked(X, Y) >= 0 then* и "if Series2.Clicked(X, Y) >= 0 then". Да они действительно (в других источниках тоже это нашел) различаются ("Step over" это довело), Но hint выводится только тот, условие которого  стоит последним в обработчике "MouseMove". Только помогает, если я создам приватную переменную (например булеву) и буду подставлять вместо "if sDayContribution.Clicked(X, Y) >= 0 then" и "if sDiffPower.Clicked(X, Y) >= 0 then"

Comment: @Konstantin78 Логично. Обработчик для нескольких графиков будет сложнее. Можно придумать даже что-то типа буфера FIFO, куда будут отсылаться строки для подсказок, а отдельный обработчик их будет выводить, удаляя по таймеру самые старые строки.